# Does it mean $|N_H|=|H|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$. Let $N_H:=\{g\in G: gHg^{-1}=H\}$ be the normalizer of $H$. I try to show that the index of $H$ in $G$ is greater than the index of $N_H$ in $G$, that is
$$
[G:N_H]\le [G:H]
$$

My proof is to use the Lagrange's theorem,
$$
|G|=|H|[G:H]=|N_H|[G:N_H]
$$
and note that $H\subset N_H$, so by $|H|\le N_H$, we complete the proof.

However, I saw a statement in the lecture note

> For a subgroup $H$ of $G$, we have
> $$
> |gHg^{-1}|=|H|
> $$

Does it mean $|N_H|=|H|$?

Comment: No. The elements of $N_H$ are the $g$s that make $gHg^{-1} = H$, not the elements of $gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The smallest counterexample is $H=\{e\}$ in $G=\Bbb Z_2$, since then $H\lhd G$, meaning

$$\boxed{N_{\Bbb Z_2}(\{e\})=\Bbb Z_2}$$

but $|\{e\}|<|\Bbb Z_2|.$

---

One of the smallest *nontrivial* counterexamples is $H=\Bbb Z_2$ in $G=\Bbb Z_4$, since then $H\lhd G$ (as $G$ is abelian), meaning

$$\boxed{N_{\Bbb Z_4}(\Bbb Z_2)=\Bbb Z_4}$$

but $|\Bbb Z_2|<|\Bbb Z_4|.$

---

I have used the more common notation of $N_G(H):=N_H.$

Comment: Is $|gHg^{-1}|=|N_H|$? Can you some examples?

Comment: No, since $|H|=|gHg^{-1}|$. Conjugation in a group is a bijection, @Hermi.

Answer (score 1):

*Consider the symmetric group* $G=S_3$ and let $H=A_3$ be the subgroup of *even permutation* then,
$|G:H|=\frac{|G|}{|H|}=\frac{3!}{3}=2$ so $H$ is normal subgroup in $G$ .

And using the following property :
$H$ is normal subgroup in $G$ *if and only if* $N_H=G$ .

we deduce that $N_{A_{3}}=S_3$ now you see that the order of $H$ is 3 and the order of $N_H$ is 6 which means $|N_H|\neq|H|$